# xcode: where can I set this Linker flag '-v'?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, swift, macos

MAC OS X. Xcode - the Linker says: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) - But where do I set this Flag?
I've tried all 'build Option' settings - I believe I have tried all of them ...

Answer (score 18):

**1.**  Select the project file from the project navigator on the far left side of the window.

**2.**   Select the target for where you want to add the linker flag.

**3.**  Select the "Build Settings" tab

**4.**  Choose "All" to show all Build Settings.

**5.**   Scroll down to the "Linking" section, and double-click to the right of where it says "Other Linking Flags".

**6.**  A box will appear, Click on the "+" button to add a new linker flag.
    Type "-v" (no quotes) and press enter.

[image]

In image set `-v` instead of `-objc`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for was. Excellent!

Comment: @Studanski  if my answer is helpful for you please mark it as answer and give me upvotes